# how to avoid too many if - else blocks in python

Tags: python, django

I wrote a class that check 4 parameters in input and shows a list a result in output.
Only one of this parameter is required, therefore i have 7 if - else nested blocks.
I want to specify that the condition as stated works properly.

I was wandering if there was a smarter way to write this:

```
if cd['subject'] is None:
    if cd['school'] == '':
        if cd['price']:
            files = File.objects.filter(name__contains=cd['name'], price = '0.0')
        else:
            files = File.objects.filter(name__contains=cd['name'])
    else:
        if cd['price']:
            files = File.objects.filter(name__contains=cd['name'], school = cd['school'], price = '0.0')
        else:
            files = File.objects.filter(name__contains=cd['name'], school = cd['school'])
else:
    if cd['school'] == '':
        if cd['price']:
            files = File.objects.filter(name__contains=cd['name'], subject = cd['subject'], price = '0.0')
        else:
            files = File.objects.filter(name__contains=cd['name'], subject = cd['subject'])
    else:
        if cd['price']:
            files = File.objects.filter(name__contains=cd['name'], school = cd['school'], subject = cd['subject'], price = '0.0')
        else:
            files = File.objects.filter(name__contains=cd['name'], school = cd['school'], subject = cd['subject'])
return render(request, 'search.html', {'files': files, 'request': request})
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation; why are you mixing `None`, empty string `''` and boolean coersion (`if <variable>`) in comparaisons?

Comment: Because the variables come from a Django form and are different form fields.
I forgot to say, the condition works just fine, I was wondering if there was a smarter (or more elegant if you may) way to say the same thing.

Comment: Very strange `cd['price']` handling

Comment: This might be better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internally, the keyword arguments you're passing to the function are just a `dict`. So build it yourself and pass it to the function using the `**name` syntax:

```
args = {}

args['name__contains'] = cd['name']

if cd['subject'] is not None:
    args['subject'] = cd['subject']
if cd['school'] != '':
    args['school'] = cd['school']
if cd['price']:
    args['price'] = cd['price']

files = File.objects.filter(**args)
return render(request, 'search.html', {'files': files, 'request': request})
```

Comment: Tuned a little the condition and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Build a dict with the keyword args for your call to `filter()`, then pass it using the `**kwargs` syntax.